# Best way to handle mutliple modals using Jquery and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a Rails application and I am looking for the best way to handle stacked modals using Jquery.

I have an action "ADD" that triggers ADD MODAL.
I have a action "FIND" which triggers a "FIND" modal and from "FIND" modal, I have an "ADD" button that will trigger the ADD modal and will hide the FIND modal.

Currently, I am closing the Find modal and triggering the ADD modal and then after successful Add, I am rendering the Find modal. (I am storing the state of Find using hidden variables and by passing it between requests)

What is the best approach for this by storing state of previous modal in Jquery?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be very broad. Please add more details, or come back with a more specific problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't say this is the best approach but it worked for me with a similar case.

What you can do is to define seperate sections within a single modal for the add and search functionality. When opening the model for Add just show the add section and when opening for Find show the find section. Now, when the modal is open for Find and you click the add button, show the add section and hide the find section. When you have executed the code for add (or cancelled it), show the find section again and hide the add section. In this way you will not bother the user with modals popping up one after another. States can be stored in hidden fields of the modal when you switch between sections. Hopefully my poor English will move you in the right direction.